# Buscar arquivo via file_exists com nome parcial

Tags: php, regex

Preciso verificar a existência de um arquivo em dois domínios.

Porém, o formato do arquivo que está gravado no banco de dados não condiz com o gravado no servidor, por uma defasagem de alguns segundos (o formato do nome do arquivo consta no exemplo abaixo).

**Arquivo que existe no servidor**
https://www.dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/consulta_87314134987_02102017135619.pdf

**Arquivo que está trazendo**
https://www.dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/consulta_87314134987_02102017135613.pdf

Como podem ver, há uma diferença nos últimos 2 caracteres (que representam os segundos... provavelmente na rotina de geração deste PDF, há um delay de alguns segundos que difere da data gravada no banco).

```
$dir01 = "https://dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/";
$dir02 = "https://dominio02.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/";

$documento = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $item['retCNPJCPF']);
$dataDoc = new DateTime($item['retDataHora']);

$filename = "consulta_".$documento."_".$dataDoc->format('dmYHis').".pdf";

if(file_exists($dir01.$filename)){
    $lnkConsultas = "Consulta disponível no dominio 01";
}
elseif(file_exists($dir02.$filename)){
    $lnkConsultas = "Consulta disponível no domínio 02";
}
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível trazer os arquivos sem a necessidade de informar os segundos, e trazer as ocorrências deste... alterando o filename, e buscar através de alguma expressão regular. Mas não faço idéia de como fazer isso.

PS: Não posso usar "glob". Com isso, será retornado resultados em branco, pois os arquivos estão em outros domínios.

Comment: Não havia lido o "Não posso usar `glob`.". :(

Comment: @Inkeliz infelizmente tentei com glob, mas o array retorna em branco :/

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente, você não irá conseguir obter o arquivo de outro servidor com regex.
A unica maneira de resolver este problema de modo fácil e prático é usando o glob, porém a listagem de diretórios deve estar **ativa**. Se o webserver for seu, simplesmente [ative-o](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731109(WS.10).aspx).
(Para mais detalhes de uma olhada [nesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4010177/7225971) publicação (en-US))

Fora isso, você só conseguirá obter os **possíveis** links se:

- Alguma página tem [a listagem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/27W6g.png) de todas as consultas (Como por exemplo: [https://www.dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/**usuario**/87314134987/](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245816/buscar-arquivo-via-file-exists-com-nome-parcial#))
- Alguma página tem [o link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrDLE.png) de todas as consultas (Como por exemplo:
  [https://www.dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/**consultas**/](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/245816/buscar-arquivo-via-file-exists-com-nome-parcial#))
- Você estiver disposto a usar **força bruta**. <sub>(<s>Não recomendado, muito esforço pra pouco resultado</s>)</sub>

## Usando força bruta

Baseando-me em sua fala: "há um delay de alguns segundos", criei uma função que procurará pelo arquivo dependendo de um *offset*, ou um número que você irá informar paraprocurar pelo arquivo, por exemplo, `forcaBruta("...13", 6)` (13 segundos), irá procurar por:

```
...13 (atual) - não encontrado
...14 (+1)    - não encontrado
...15 (+2)    - não encontrado
...16 (+3)    - não encontrado
...17 (+4)    - não encontrado
...18 (+5)    - não encontrado
...19 (+6)    - arquivo encontrado
```

Lógicamente, o offset não irá testar por números menores pois o servidor receberá o arquivo depois de você (se esse não for o caso, simplesmente arrume a função para `"-1 second"`):

```
<?php
    use \DateTime as DT;
    function forcaBruta($consulta, $offset = 0){
        preg_match("/_(\d+?)\.pdf$/", $consulta, $arr); // Obtem os ultimos números do arquivo
        $dataDoc = DT::createFromFormat("dmYHis", $arr[sizeof($arr)-1]); // Cria um DateTime com o número recebido para não haver erros na força bruta (ex.: 61 segundos)
        for ($x=0; $x<=$offset; $x++) {
            $url = preg_replace("/_\d+.pdf$/", "_".$dataDoc->format("dmYHis").".pdf", $consulta);   // Obtem o novo URL
            if (@fopen($file, "r")) // Se possível, substitua para file_exists(), no meu caso, não estava funcionando...
                return $url; // Retorna o URL novo se ele existir
            $dataDoc->modify("+1 second"); // Adiciona 1 segundo ao doc da data ("-1 second" pra fazer o inverso)
        }
        return false;
    }
?>
```

Desta forma, ao usar:

```
forcaBruta("https://www.dominio01.com.br/sistema/modulos/consulta/consultas/consulta_87314134987_02102017135613.pdf", 6)
```

a função retornará o url do arquivo existente de `02102017135613` até `02102017135619`, se não existir, então retornará `false`.

---

## Demonstração:

[image: Demonstração]